# How can i write Addon/Plugin-friendly code?

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

i want to know how i can make my code Plugin/Priendliy.
Lets say :

I have a program and on the User interface there would be an Addons section , where other developers can offer Plugins.But how do i have to design such an interface , that my code works with other code. i can't imagine :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Template Method Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what language/platform you're looking at. If it's .NET have a look at MEF:

http://www.codeplex.com/MEF

It's at least a good place to start if you're looking for a pattern to work from.

Comment: its not a language specific question . it s more about software desing

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look to XPCOM or OSGi.

Answer (score 0):

Look at some software which does this as core functionality. For instance, MediaPortal, MediaPortal2, and MeedioOS have this functionality built in.